# Possibility of nursing in Europe...South African with Italian passport

Tags: schengen

My Italian husband and I want to move to Italy. Unfortunately I can't speak Italian which would makes it difficult to find a job in Italy. How difficult would it be for me to work in a European country where they speak English? I am a nurse.

Comment: If you live in Italy it will be very difficult because commuting to the UK or Ireland from Italy would be difficult.  Are you considering settling there instead of in Italy?

Comment: We just thought it would be easier because of his Italian citizenship. But we are open to any suggestions.

Comment: You can move to any EU country because of his Italian citizenship, including Ireland and the UK.  The situation in the UK is somewhat iffy at the moment, of course.  In other EU countries, speaking only English will be more or less of a disadvantage.  Your other problem, of course, is going to be getting nursing credentials in the country you want to work in, and I am afraid I don't know anything about that.

Comment: I have to work where they speak English because I have to register with their nursing council and therefore have to write an exam.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the political situation in the UK, foreign nurses who can communicate in English are still in demand. If you both have Italian passports you can relocate to UK as soon as you are ready, and you can apply to the Nursing and Midwifery Council to register as a nurse. You would have to pass their 'adaptation' requirements which include a period of supervised practice.

Comment: It should not be necessary for both spouses to have Italian passports.  As long as the UK remains in the EU, the non-Italian spouse can enter relatively easily with an EEA family permit, which is free of charge and for which there is no test of financial means.